# Having trouble editing Finder settings using defaults write

Tags: finder, command-line, defaults

I run the following command:

```
sudo defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop -boolean TRUE
```

in hopes that this will cause system hard drives to show on the desktop, which doesn't happen.  I kill all Finder processes and restart Finder, but no dice.

I try to open com.apple.finder.plist in Xcode, but it says I do not have permissions to view the file (I was able to before).  Shortly after, I am able to open it, but the file is empty.  The attributes are slowly regenerating.

What is happening here?  I am looking for a command to toggle the option to show hard drives on the desktop, just as if I checked the box in Finder preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't need `sudo` and it may have caused the permissions issue, and no need to use the full pathname, just:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop -boolean TRUE
```

The following works for me, as is, in OS X 10.8.5 and macOS 10.12.5 in both a Standard and Admin Account in Terminal.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop -boolean TRUE; killall Finder
```

Using `FALSE`, in place of `TRUE` hides the e.g. Macintosh HD on the Desktop.

I'd probably opt to either restore the file from a known good backup or delete the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` file and then run `killall Finder` in Terminal, letting it rebuild and should resolve the permissions issue as well.

Comment: That worked for me.  I think my problem had to do with me using 'sudo' and running 'killall Finder' in a separate line, after the running Finder process already messed things up.

Comment: @squarjn, Running `killall Finder` on a separate line should not be an issue, I just do it all on one line for efficiency. The real issue was you using `sudo`, as you shouldn't have in this use case.